# How do Backed Collections work in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, list

In Java,I have the following array 'integerArray' and add 2 integers to it.

```
Integer[] integerArray = new Integer[3];
integerArray[0] = 1;
integerArray[1] = 2;
```

Now I create a list out of the Array.

```
List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(integerArray);
```

At this point,the 'integerList' contains 1 and 2.

Now I add another element to the array.

```
integerArray[2] = 3;
```

At this point,if we examine the integerList,we see that it contains 1,2,3;

What mechanism is used so that any changes to the Array are reflected in the List as well? A simple implementation or example will really help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array

This means that the returned list object, which is actually an `ArrayList`, has a *reference* to the array, as opposed to a *copy*. Since it has a reference to this array, any changes to it will be reflected in the list.

The method `Arrays.asList` just calls the constructor of `ArrayList` defined as follows:

```
ArrayList (E[] array) {
    if (array == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    a = array;
}
```

So the field `a` will store the reference to your initial array.

Answer (score 4):

This is because it is the same variable but used as a list. If you read the Javadoc for [Arrays.asList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...))

It states clearly

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination with Collection.toArray(). The returned list is serializable and implements RandomAccess.

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.asList` is a static/utility method that invokes the constructor to create a new ArrayList. The ArrayList is backed by an Array. This is the case in a lot of programming languages, where advance data structures are simply backed by primitive arrays. You can look at the source code here [Arrays.asList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.asList%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)